# I don't understand why some of the random colors are overlapping the image?

Tags: javascript, css, image, background-color

I followed a tutorial on the youtube channel online tutorials the video is called change image color vanilla javascript. I don't understand why some of the random colors on the click event overlap the image instead of changing only the color of the cats eye? Is there a way to fix this? Maybe I just need to find an image that works for this particular functionality? I also don't understand part of the code where I commented. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Change image color</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <img src="images/cat-2143332_1920.jpg" alt="">

    <div id="bg"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const bg = document.getElementById('bg');
        function randomColor() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        }
        // I don't understand How this works??
        bg.addEventListener('click', () => {
            bg.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(' + randomColor() + ',' + randomColor() + ',' + randomColor() + ')';
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#bg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    mix-blend-mode: hue;
}
```

[image: Cat image]

Comment: this code adds an color to the div tagged with `#bg` and since its just `width: 100%` and `height: 100vh` it will jump ontop of the image and completely change it's color

Comment: and about the `eventListener`, that piece of code will look at `#bg`, since it says `bg.addEventListener`, and then looks for something, in this case a click event: `('click', () => {` and when clicked, it will change the color of `#bg` with a random given color code

Comment: for further questions, you can pm me if you wish to have a chat :)

Comment: Concerning the JS code, there should be a `randomColor()` function that will return a value between 0 and 256. `rgba()` is a CSS function that takes in 3 color values and an opacity and creates the color from those. Compare with using a `#CDEF55` string or color name, `blue`, to signify a color. So the event creates a random color, like `rgba( 253, 14, 25 )` and the updates the style of the div to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is changing the background behind the image. The image uses a hue styled blend mode, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/blend-mode#hue, which gives it that effect when the background changes. You can try other blend modes too.

As for the line you are confused about; all that does is make a random color. RGBA stands for Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha, and the color values range from 0 to 255. Try pasting the below code into the developer console a few times to see what happens.

```
function randomColor() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        }
console.log('rgba(' + randomColor() + ',' + randomColor() + ',' + randomColor() + ',1.0)');
```

Indeed that is a strange bug. Does the code at https://jsfiddle.net/m0ose/w7dqg4a6/3/ still have the bug you are talking about? I added a `user-select:none` to the css.

Comment: Is there a way to fix the overlapping color?

Comment: It looks like the use-select is responsible. try changing the css ` user-select:none;` to the image in the css. Here is an example with the change https://jsfiddle.net/m0ose/w7dqg4a6/3/